# ¿Cómo insertar solo registros que no estén en la tabla destino?

Tags: sql, sql-server

El inconveniente que tengo es que tengo una tabla que ya tiene ciertos valores, le estoy intentando insertar mas valores pero existe alguna forma de al momento de insertar los otros valores, me haga una validación para saber si esos valores ya están en la tabla, si están que no los inserte y si no están entonces que si los inserte

¿Alguien sabra alguna forma de poder hacer eso?

Quizas alguna condicionante en el `INSERT`

El error que me genera es el siguiente

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 23 Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__UIF03_Tr__68F026224AA5172F'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas'. The duplicate key value is (202105311705180657613674). The statement has been terminated.
```

¿Se le puede poner un `where` a un `insert` indicando que me inserte datos que no estén en la tabla?

¿O si es con un trigger como seria?

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATETIME;
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATETIME;

DECLARE @DiasMes INT = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FechaInicio, @FechaFinal);
DECLARE @MesReportar VARCHAR(10) = FORMAT(@FechaInicio, 'yyyyMM');
DECLARE @MontoLimiteHNL DECIMAL(18, 4) = 200000;

SET @FechaInicio = '2021-05-01';
SET @FechaFinal = '2021-05-31';

INSERT INTO dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas(
                                                   FechaReportada
                                                 , BPId
                                                 , TipoInstitucion
                                                 , CodigoInstitucion
                                                 , CodigoSucursal
                                                 , CodigoAgencia
                                                 , FechaReportaDatos
                                                 , NumeroTransaccion
                                               )
SELECT  
 FORMAT(@FechaInicio, 'yyyyMM')                                                     AS 'FechaReportada'
,bp.BPId
,'01'          AS [TipoInstitucion]
,'34'          AS [CodigoInstitucion]
,'01'          AS [CodigoSucursal]
,'01'          AS [CodigoAgencia]
,FORMAT(@FechaFinal, 'yyyyMMdd')                                                                   AS [FechaReportaDatos]
,CONCAT(
            FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0'
          , CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), bp.BPId))                                                         AS [NumeroTransaccion]

FROM    CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BusinessProcesses bp WITH ( NOLOCK )
     INNER JOIN CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpcr ON bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId
```

Este es el query que estoy usando

Comment: ¿No sería mejor poner la columna con el atributo Unique?

Comment: Investiga sobre los triggers

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar la definición de la tabla a la pregunta?

Comment: Al menos agrega la sentencia de insert a tu pregunta, sino cualquier respuesta es pura especulación.

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Comment: Corregí el formato de tu pregunta, sugiero que le des clic en [edit] y observes como se hace. También recomiendo que cuides tu ortografía y puntuación, son importantes para que se entienda el mensaje que quieres transmitir.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos posibles problemas con tu consulta:

1. No estás validando información que ya pueda existir en la tabla.
2. No estás previniendo que la consulta traiga datos duplicados.

Para solucionar el primer problema, podemos escribir la consulta de la siguiente forma (cambié la función FORMAT porque es muy ineficiente).

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas(
    FechaReportada
    , BPId
    , TipoInstitucion
    , CodigoInstitucion
    , CodigoSucursal
    , CodigoAgencia
    , FechaReportaDatos
    , NumeroTransaccion
)
SELECT  
         CONVERT( char(6), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,bp.BPId
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'34'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,CONVERT( char(8), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId)
FROM       CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BusinessProcesses bp WITH ( NOLOCK )
INNER JOIN CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpcr ON bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas tr Pa
                  WHERE tr.NumeroTransaccion = CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId));
```

Para solucionar el segundo problema puedes agregar la palabra DISTINCT.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas(
    FechaReportada
    , BPId
    , TipoInstitucion
    , CodigoInstitucion
    , CodigoSucursal
    , CodigoAgencia
    , FechaReportaDatos
    , NumeroTransaccion
)
SELECT  DISTINCT
         CONVERT( char(6), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,bp.BPId
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'34'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,CONVERT( char(8), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId)
FROM       CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BusinessProcesses bp WITH ( NOLOCK )
INNER JOIN CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpcr ON bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas tr Pa
                  WHERE tr.NumeroTransaccion = CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId));
```

Sin embargo, en vez de eliminar duplicados es mejor prevenirlos desde un inicio.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas(
    FechaReportada
    , BPId
    , TipoInstitucion
    , CodigoInstitucion
    , CodigoSucursal
    , CodigoAgencia
    , FechaReportaDatos
    , NumeroTransaccion
)
SELECT  
         CONVERT( char(6), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,bp.BPId
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'34'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,'01'                                                      
        ,CONVERT( char(8), @FechaInicio, 112)                      
        ,CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId)
FROM       CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BusinessProcesses bp WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpcr WHERE bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId)
AND   NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas tr Pa
                  WHERE tr.NumeroTransaccion = CONCAT(FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0', bp.BPId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz un left join con la tabla de destino, y especifica en la unión como se relacionan (en este caso sería el campo marcado con uniquekey) y pones el filtro donde tabla_de_destino.id is null.

Lo que pasaría sería lo siguiente: por ejemplo imagina que en la tabla dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas tengo los id 1,2 (donde Id sería tu columna uniquekey) y en el select  de bp y bpcr se generan registros con id 1,3 al hacer el left join dejando la tabla UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas al lado derecho de la consulta, entonces traerá todos los registros de bp y bpcr aunque no existan en UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas, por lo que la unión sería

```
bp+bpcr   UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas 
1         1
3         NULL(Porque el id 3 no existe aún)
```

Luego en el where dejo que me filtre los registros donde UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas  IS NULL (ojo no es que UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas.Id = null, la instrucción es UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas .Id IS NULL), al hacer ese filtro solo dejarás los registros relacionados donde UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas.Id es null, y el que cumple la condición en nuestro ejemplo es el de id 3 y así evitamos el de id 1 que ya existe.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesas(
                                                   FechaReportada
                                                 , BPId
                                                 , TipoInstitucion
                                                 , CodigoInstitucion
                                                 , CodigoSucursal
                                                 , CodigoAgencia
                                                 , FechaReportaDatos
                                                 , NumeroTransaccion
                                                 
                                               )
                                       


SELECT  

 FORMAT(@FechaInicio, 'yyyyMM')                                                     AS 'FechaReportada'
,bp.BPId
,'01'          AS [TipoInstitucion]
,'34'          AS [CodigoInstitucion]
,'01'          AS [CodigoSucursal]
,'01'          AS [CodigoAgencia]
,FORMAT(@FechaFinal, 'yyyyMMdd')                                                                   AS [FechaReportaDatos]
,CONCAT(
            FORMAT(bp.Created, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss'), '0'
          , CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), bp.BPId))                                                         AS [NumeroTransaccion]

FROM    CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BusinessProcesses bp WITH ( NOLOCK )
     INNER JOIN CWCORE2.CWNET_HON.dbo.BPClientsRelations AS bpcr ON bpcr.BPId = bp.BPId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UIF03_TransferenciasRemesa r on r.BPId = bp.BPId --(Ojo acá la relación debe ser con tu campo uniquekey, es decir el dato que se está repitiendo, no lo especificas así que yo concluyo que es BPId)
WHERE r.BPId IS NULL
```